# SenchaCMD Error during refresh or build

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have an error with SenchaCMD 4.0.2.67. When I try to run `sencha app refresh` or `sencha app build` or `sencha ant phonegap-sencha-build` on the terminal, I get the following error:

```
...

[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Loading classpath entry /path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/touch/src
[INF] Loading classpath entry /path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/app.js
[INF] Loading classpath entry /path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/app
[INF] Loading classpath entry /path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/Ux
[INF] Loading classpath entry /path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/build/temp/production/Inpunkto/sencha-compiler/app
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.ReferenceVisitor.processObjectAutoDependencies(Refe
[ERR] renceVisitor.java:303)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.ReferenceVisi
[ERR] tor.processObjectAutoDependencies(ReferenceVisitor.java:303)
[ERR]   at org.mozilla.javascript.ast.FunctionNode.visit(Func
[ERR] tionNode.java:421)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.comp
[ERR] iler.sources.ReferenceVisitor.processObjectAutoDependencies(ReferenceVisitor.java:303)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.processInstanceConfig(InstanceConfigReferenceProcess
[ERR] or.java:128)
[ERR]   at org.mozilla.javascript.ast.Block.visit(Block
[ERR] .java:61)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.processInstanceConfig(Inst
[ERR] anceConfigReferenceProcessor.java:131)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.InstanceConfigReferen
[ERR] ceProcessor.processInstanceConfig(InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.java:128)
[ERR]   at org.mozilla.javascript.ast.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStat
[ERR] ement.java:120)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sou
[ERR] rces.InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.processInstanceConfig(InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.java:131)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.processInstanceConfigForClass(InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.java:
[ERR] 179)
[ERR]   at org
[ERR] .mozilla.javascript.ast.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:120)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 2 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/matthias/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67/plugins/touch/2.3/plugin.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:367: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/path/to/project/senchatouch/projects/inpunkto/.sencha/app/js-impl.xml:11: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
```

I have a SenchaTouch 2.3.1 app and integrated the newest release of phonegap into it by using the command: `sencha phonegap init [AppID]`.

Can anybody tell my what this error is all about?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are building a code created with sencha architect. Please create a separate project using sencha generate app..  command and then copy the contents from this project to newly created project. Make necessary changes whereever needed, such as project name in each file, etc. I think it will work fine after that...

Comment: That didn't help. I made a complete new project with SenchaCMD and copied the needed files from the app directory into the new project (models, views, controllers, etc.). When I use "sencha app refresh" or anything else the same error appears